# AngularJS ng-click broken by {{$index}}

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with AngularJS where when I use $index it breaks the ng-click function.

This is being done within a div that uses ng-repeat, the repeat code works correctly...

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-parent="#acc{{$index}}" ng-click="sayhi('{{ $index }}');" 
href="javascript:void(0);"> TEST </a>
```

When I click, it does nothing.  I check the generated HTML and it does have ng-click="sayHi('0')", but the click event doesn't work.

Alternatively, if I change the ng-click to be:

```
ng-click="sayhi('0');"
```

without using {{$index}} to generate the zero, it works perfectly...

I've tried with angular 1.0.6 and 1.2.0

Also, I'm using jQuery 1.7 and bootstrap 3.0 if that makes a difference.

Has anyone run into this?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
ng-click="sayhi($index)"
```

as `ng-click` doesn't support interpolation (`{{ }}`) AFAIK only valid [angular expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Comment: Derp... that was it, I should have known I ran into the same related thing before.. Thanks!